# Problem when redefining the list of figures

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

When I redefine in a separate preambule `\listoffigures` I get a blank page in my test file, I'm going to post in this question only the code of the redefinition.

```
\titlecontents{figure}
  [0em]{}
  {\color{blue}\thecontentslabel\hspace*{1.5em}}
  {}{\color{red}\dotfill\textcolor{blue}{\contentspage}}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{
\newpage

\vspace*{1cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]%
\node[] at ([yshift=12cm]current page.center){\color{red}\Huge\scshape\bfseries Liste des figures:};
\end{tikzpicture}
\vspace{1cm}
\@starttoc{loF}
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: please show an example that shows your problem. `\titlecontents` is not a standard command, how is it defined?